# Распарсить ID трека Spotify

Tags: python, json

Делаю программу для импорта музыки с ВК в Спотифай. Библиотеки: vk_api, spotipy

Код функции выглядит так:

```
for i in vk_audio_list.get(owner_id=*ID страницы в ВК*):
        searchName = i['artist'] + ' ' + i['title']
        results = sp.search(q=searchName, type = 'track', limit=1)
        for k in enumerate(results):
            sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playid, addtrack, position=None)
```

Данным циклом я получаю аудиозаписи c ВК:

```
for i in vk_audio_list.get(owner_id=*ID страницы в ВК*):
```

Далее я получаю список песен и "отправляю" их на поиск в спотифай:

```
    searchName = i['artist'] + ' ' + i['title']
    results = sp.search(q=searchName, type = 'track', limit=1)
```

В переменную results записываются json данные, для примера:

```
{'tracks': {'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=RSAC+%D0%9B%D0%91%D0%AE%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AC&type=track&offset=0&limit=1', 'items': [{'album': {'album_type': 'album', 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic', 'id': '73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic', 'name': 'RSAC', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AL', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BA', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'BY', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MK', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'UA', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'XK', 'ZA'], 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7fRYQQQeZsZeFhmySpVw8B'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7fRYQQQeZsZeFhmySpVw8B', 'id': '7fRYQQQeZsZeFhmySpVw8B', 'images': [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27338a1266173326dd32c5c7a2d', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0238a1266173326dd32c5c7a2d', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485138a1266173326dd32c5c7a2d', 'width': 64}], 'name': 'АРГУМЕНТЫ', 'release_date': '2018-10-26', 'release_date_precision': 'day', 'total_tracks': 9, 'type': 'album', 'uri': 'spotify:album:7fRYQQQeZsZeFhmySpVw8B'}, 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic', 'id': '73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic', 'name': 'RSAC', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:73GvUkYDMIcPNepUhyC8ic'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AL', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BA', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'BY', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MK', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'UA', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'XK', 'ZA'], 'disc_number': 1, 'duration_ms': 169928, 'explicit': False, 'external_ids': {'isrc': 'FR96X1855525'}, 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/3HbjiEtYEmjRxcUKI8LAJe'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3HbjiEtYEmjRxcUKI8LAJe', 'id': '3HbjiEtYEmjRxcUKI8LAJe', 'is_local': False, 'name': 'ЛБЮОВЬ', 'popularity': 20, 'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/32fb7e68053f9ffc5aea669cc4f0078e91cdf201?cid=f248f398da6d42cd9f5c1240a4a3b950', 'track_number': 1, 'type': 'track', 'uri': 'spotify:track:3HbjiEtYEmjRxcUKI8LAJe'}], 'limit': 1, 'next': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=RSAC+%D0%9B%D0%91%D0%AE%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AC&type=track&offset=1&limit=1', 'offset': 0, 'previous': None, 'total': 2}}
```

В конце есть uri трека, как раз его мне надо получить и передать в следующий цикл

```
'uri': 'spotify:track:3HbjiEtYEmjRxcUKI8LAJe'}
```

Следующий цикл выглядит так, по сути он должен получить uri трека и передать его в addtrack и, соответственно, добавить этот трек в плейлист. Но тут я как раз застопился.

```
for k in enumerate(results):
                sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playid, addtrack, position=None)
```

Как мне реализовать последний цикл, чтоб он получал uri трека и добавлял его в плейлист?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
#Получаем ответ в формате JSON, я так понимаю 
results = sp.search(q=searchName, type = 'track', limit=1)

#Распарсиваем в словарь 
data = json.loads(results)

#Получаем его "uri" по ключу (Основываясь на примере ваших данных) и передаем в функцию 
for track in data['tracks']['items']:
    track_uri = track.get('uri')
    sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playid, track_uri, position=None)
```

Comment: Только замечу что делать `.get` нужно только в тех случаях когда ожидается `None`. Если поле всегда присутствует, то лучше использовать `["uri"]`.

Comment: @PavelDurmanov благодарю за подсказку. Но все-таки чем лучше обращение именно через квадратные скобки? Или это является хорошим тоном или как? Мне это действительно интересно узнать для себя на будущее

Comment: Когда кто-то будет читать ваш код и увидит .get, он подумает что вы ожидаете None, и будет искать где и как вы его хендлите. Еще одна принича это трайсбеки, если из гета вернулся None которого мы не ожидали, трайсбек может быть непонятным, хотя это по факту банальный KeyError.